# Problem with PHP OCI8 oci_bind_array_by_name using SQLT_BDOUBLE (Oracle BINARY_DOUBLE)

Tags: php, oracle, oci8

I am having trouble getting oci_bind_array_by_name() to work with the type "SQLT_BDOUBLE"

I get "oci_bind_array_by_name(): Unknown or unsupported datatype given: 22"

The UDT:

```
   TYPE double_array IS TABLE OF BINARY_DOUBLE INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;
```

I am able to successfully use "SQLT_NUM" with type "number_array":

```
TYPE number_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER;
```

However, when I attempt to call the binary_double version using

```
$values= array();
$values[] = 123.45678;
oci_bind_array_by_name($stmt,':p_values',$values, count($values), -1,SQLT_BDOUBLE );
```

It returns "oci_bind_array_by_name(): Unknown or unsupported datatype given: 22"

I also tried using SQLT_FLT, SQLT_NUM, and also not passing a type to try and let OCI8 figure it out, but those all return "ORA-06550: line 1, column 111: PLS-00418: array bind type must match PL/SQL table row type"  -which makes sense.

Is it it a version issue with OCI8 and Oracle Instant Client ?  PHP version ???
I don't know where to go from here.

This is Oracle 12c, Oracle 12c InstantClient, PHP 7.4 with supplied oci8_12c (XAMPP)  on Windows 10.

Code to create Oracle objects;

```
CREATE USER test
    IDENTIFIED BY "Ab1-Cd2_Ef3^Gh4"
    ACCOUNT UNLOCK;
    
create or replace PACKAGE test.ts_test
as
   TYPE number_array IS TABLE OF NUMBER INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   TYPE bdouble_array IS TABLE OF BINARY_DOUBLE  INDEX BY BINARY_INTEGER;

   PROCEDURE test_number_array (
      p_times IN number_array
      );

   PROCEDURE test_bdouble_array (
      p_values IN bdouble_array
    );    
end ts_test;



create or replace PACKAGE BODY test.ts_test
as                          
   PROCEDURE test_number_array( p_times IN number_array )
   IS
        l_nothing number;
   BEGIN
       select p_times(0) into l_nothing from dual;  
   END test_number_array;                           

   PROCEDURE test_bdouble_array( p_values IN bdouble_array )
   IS
      l_nothing BINARY_DOUBLE;
   BEGIN
       select p_values(0) into l_nothing from dual; 
   END test_bdouble_array;   
     
end ts_test;   


grant execute on test.ts_test to <user>;
```

Tests:
(1) BINARY_DOUBLE - fails

```
<?php
$dbstr = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>) ))";
$conn = oci_pconnect('user', 'pass', $dbstr) or die (ocierror());

$sql = 'begin   test.ts_test.test_bdouble_array( :p_values );  end; ';
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

$values = array();
$values[] = 23.4567;
$values[] = 34.5678;

oci_bind_array_by_name($stmt,':p_values',$values,count($values), -1, SQLT_BDOUBLE );
$status = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

$e = oci_error($stmt);
if ($e) { print htmlentities($e['message']); } else { print("success"); }

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

(2) NUMBER - works

```
<?php
$dbstr = "(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(HOST =localhost)(PORT = 1521)) (CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = DEDICATED) (SERVICE_NAME = <service_name>) ))";
$conn = oci_pconnect('user', 'pass', $dbstr) or die (ocierror());

$sql = 'begin   test.ts_test.test_number_array( :p_times );  end; ';
$stmt = oci_parse($conn, $sql);

$times = array();
$times[] = strtotime('08/14/2021 11:00:00');

oci_bind_array_by_name($stmt,':p_times',$values,count($times), -1, SQLT_NUM );
$status = oci_execute($stmt, OCI_COMMIT_ON_SUCCESS);

$e = oci_error($stmt);
if ($e) { print htmlentities($e['message']); } else { print("success"); }

oci_free_statement($stmt);
oci_close($conn);
```

Comment: Update your question with the SQL to create the table and package, and with a complete, runnable PHP script, e.g https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: Yes -thank you I updated with examples and code.